# How to read string from text file

Tags: python

I have a text file containing following information:
['123', '456', '789']
I would like to read each of them from this file as an individual integer each time. For example, the first time get 123 as integer, the second time get 456 as integer, ...

What is the easiest way to do? Thanks!

Comment: You have a single line in a file containing exactly that?

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
with open('file.txt') as myfile:
    info = myfile.readline()
```

Note that the list will be a string, and not a list object. To convert it to a list, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
info = ast.literal_eval(info)
```

Now use a simple loop:

```
for i in info:
    print int(i)
```

Prints:

```
123
456
789
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")           //Opens the file and stores it in a variable

for line in f:                      //It says; for every line in the file f, do following:
        line = int(line)            //converts the variable 'line' to an int
        print(line)                    //prints the variable
```

if you want to be sure that the variable 'line' is of data type int
you can squeeze in `print(type(line))` to the code

output:

```
123
456
789
```

=) I'm sure this is the easiest way!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('file') as fin:
    for number in map(int, literal_eval(next(fin, '[]'))):
        print number
```